# Convert Pandas DataFrame to JSON format

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas `DataFrame` with two columns – one with the filename and one with the hour in which it was generated:

```
 File       Hour
  F1         1
  F1         2
  F2         1
  F3         1
```

I am trying to convert it to a JSON file with the following format:

```
{"File":"F1","Hour":"1"} 
{"File":"F1","Hour":"2"}
{"File":"F2","Hour":"1"}
{"File":"F3","Hour":"1"}
```

When I use the command `DataFrame.to_json(orient = "records")`, I get the records in the below format:

```
[{"File":"F1","Hour":"1"},
 {"File":"F1","Hour":"2"},
 {"File":"F2","Hour":"1"},
 {"File":"F3","Hour":"1"}]
```

I'm just wondering whether there is an option to get the JSON file in the desired format. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you want isn't proper `json`.  What you get from `dataframe.to_json(orient = “records”)` is proper `json`

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The output that you get after [`DF.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) is a `string`. So, you can simply slice it according to your requirement and remove the commas from it too.

```
out = df.to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace('},{', '} {')
```

To write the output to a text file, you could do:

```
with open('file_name.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(out)
```

Comment: This removes the commas between two key values pairs : {"ServerGroup":"Map""Hour":0}. I need it to be {"ServerGroup":"Map","Hour":0}.

Comment: Yeah, that was my mistake. Please try the modified one.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. Initially I used to convert the dataframe to a json file and store it in a local file using "df1.to_json(orient='records',path_or_buf='/content/tmp/GoogleCount.json')[1:-1].replace('},{','} {')". But now after the replace statement, I get the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Comment: That's because it's no longer a `json` formatted object but rather a `json-string`. Try passing `path_or_buf=None` as the argument instead.

Comment: Ok Thanks. But I need to save this in a file, just wondering is there a way to achieve it

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'to_json'

Comment: Instead of writing the output , how can I view one record? The file is too huge to write out just for viewing content.

Answer (score 98):

In newer versions of pandas (0.20.0+, I believe), this can be done directly:

```
df.to_json('temp.json', orient='records', lines=True)
```

Direct compression is also possible:

```
df.to_json('temp.json.gz', orient='records', lines=True, compression='gzip')
```

Comment: best solution imho!

Comment: JEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEZ I had been stuck on this for so long and it was so dumb and you've saved me thanks so much (I couldn't use temporary CSVs for some reason), anyway, THANKS!!

Answer (score 31):

I think what the OP is looking for is:

```
with open('temp.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df.to_json(orient='records', lines=True))
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Should be top answer. Clear and concise.

Answer (score 14):

Try this one:

```
json.dumps(json.loads(df.to_json(orient="records")))
```

Answer (score 10):

use this formula to convert a pandas DataFrame to a list of dictionaries :

```
import json
json_list = json.loads(json.dumps(list(DataFrame.T.to_dict().values())))
```

Answer (score 4):

convert data-frame to list of dictionary

```
list_dict = []

for index, row in list(df.iterrows()):
    list_dict.append(dict(row))
```

save file

```
with open("output.json", mode) as f:
    f.write("\n".join(str(item) for item in list_dict))
```

Answer (score 1):

To transform a dataFrame in a real json (not a string) I use:

```
    from io import StringIO
    import json
    import DataFrame

    buff=StringIO()
    #df is your DataFrame
    df.to_json(path_or_buf=buff,orient='records')
    dfJson=json.loads(buff)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `dataframe.to_json(orient = “records”)` 
use `dataframe.to_json(orient = “index”)`
my above code convert the dataframe into json format of dict like {index -> {column -> value}}

Comment: Maybe, this would be dependent on the orientation of the data you are trying to use.

Answer (score -2):

Here is small utility class that converts JSON to DataFrame and back: Hope you find this helpful.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

class DFConverter:

    #Converts the input JSON to a DataFrame
    def convertToDF(self,dfJSON):
        return(json_normalize(dfJSON))

    #Converts the input DataFrame to JSON 
    def convertToJSON(self, df):
        resultJSON = df.to_json(orient='records')
        return(resultJSON)
```

Comment: Works, but actually just a wrapper for the same available oneliner functions. I think most of the cases this is unwarranted in this form.