# How to convert this tabular panda dataframe with row name into this json format?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the panda dataframe `df` below;

```
        File       Hour
Name1   F1         1
Name2   F1         2
```

I want to convert it into json that looks like this;

```
{
    "Name1": {
        "File": "F1",
        "Hour": "1"
    },
    "Name2": {
        "File": "F2",
        "Hour": "2"
    }
}
```

How can I use [`df.to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) to do this? I am welcomed to using other methods.

I am using python v3.9

Comment: `df.T.to_json()` or `df.to_json(orient='index')`

Comment: I would like to answer my own question, thanks to mozway comment. How do I do that now that the question is closed?

Comment: You don't need to, the question already has an answer in the duplicate ;)

Comment: @mozway, that question is not as helpful as your straightforward comment. That question has several answers which confuses a newbie like me. Stackoverflow experts cannot assume people like me is as smart as them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257147/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-json-format), you can use [`to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) this way:

```
df.to_json(orient='index')
```

or

```
df.T.to_json()
```

output:

```
'{"Name1":{"File":"F1","Hour":1},"Name2":{"File":"F1","Hour":2}}'
```