How to get a list from a dataframe value instead of string
I have an excel file with a structure as the following:



Title
List




Title_1
['str_1', 'str_2']


Title_2
['str_3', 'str_4']



and I want to get the data in a json structure as:
{"0":{"Title": "Title_1", "List": ['str_1', 'str_2']}, "1":{"Title": "Title_2", "List": ['str_3', 'str_4']}}

instead of:
{"0":{"Title": "Title_1", "List": "['str_1', 'str_2']"}, "1":{"Title": "Title_2", "List": "['str_3', 'str_4']"}}

How can I achieve this by using the pandas module in python?
I have tried:
df = pd.read_excel("my_excel.xlsx")

df.to_dict("index")

and get:
{"0":{"Title": "Title_1", "List": "['str_1', 'str_2']"}, "1":{"Title": "Title_2", "List": "['str_3', 'str_4']"}}


Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257147/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-json-format

To get your desired datatype you can try the following transformation:
import ast
def convert_to_list(string_value):
try:
    return ast.literal_eval(string_value)
except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
    return string_value

df['List'] = df['List'].apply(convert_to_list)

This function simply takes a string value and do the following:

Safely tries to convert the input string as a Python literal expression(a list)
If the input string can be converted to a list, it will return a list otherwise in case there's a ValueError or SyntaxError it will return the original string value


This method works, thank you.

You can select this as your accepted answer

If you want to use the pandas library, you can use the Dataframe method to_json. This will give you the JSON structure of the dataframe.
df.to_json(orient="index")

To validate the result you can use:
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(df.to_json(orient="index")), orient="index")


Maybe I have misunderstood the codes, I cannot work out the wanted result with the codes.

What is the result or error you get?
